# ExceptionInInitializerError when running EvoSuite(automated unit test generation for java)

Tags: java, exception

I have the following very simple, purposefully buggy java class:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;
public class ArrayListError{

public ArrayListError(){
}
public static void makeArray(int i){
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(i);
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
System.out.println("Enter a number to create arrayList:");
Scanner scanner =new Scanner(System.in);
int i= scanner.nextInt();
makeArray(i);
}

}
```

When running on evosuite cygwin( java -jar evosuite-20120511.jar -setup c:/Users/Eliezer\ Shindler/Desktop/myclasses)
 I get:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at de.unisb.cs.st.evosuite.setup.ScanProject.main(ScanProject.java:578)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot const           ruct de.unisb.cs.st.evosuite.callgraph.DistanceTransformer$ClassEntry as it does            not have a no-args constructor : Cannot construct de.unisb.cs.st.evosuite.callg           raph.DistanceTransformer$ClassEntry as it does not have a no-args constructor
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Cannot construct de.unisb.cs.st.evosuite.callgraph.Distanc           eTransformer$ClassEntry as it does not have a no-args constructor
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ObjectAcces           sException
cause-message       : Cannot construct de.unisb.cs.st.evosuite.callgraph.Distanc           eTransformer$ClassEntry as it does not have a no-args constructor
class               : java.util.HashSet
required-type       : de.unisb.cs.st.evosuite.callgraph.DistanceTransformer$Clas           sEntry
path                : /set/de.unisb.cs.st.evosuite.callgraph.DistanceTransformer           $ClassEntry

### line number         : 2

```
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshall           er.java:89)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(A           bstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:63)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnm           arshaller.java:76)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnm           arshaller.java:60)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionCon           verter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.p           opulateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:68)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.u           nmarshal(CollectionConverter.java:61)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshall           er.java:82)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(A           bstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:63)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnm           arshaller.java:76)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnm           arshaller.java:60)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller           .java:137)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarsh           al(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:33)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:923)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:909)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:853)
    at de.unisb.cs.st.evosuite.utils.Utils.readXML(Utils.java:301)
    at de.unisb.cs.st.evosuite.callgraph.Hierarchy.readFromDefaultLocation(H           ierarchy.java:113)
    at de.unisb.cs.st.evosuite.setup.TestTaskGenerator.<clinit>(TestTaskGene           rator.java:57)
    ... 1 more
```

Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ObjectAccessException:            Cannot construct de.unisb.cs.st.evosuite.callgraph.DistanceTransformer$ClassEnt           ry as it does not have a no-args constructor
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProv           ider.newInstance(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:71)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConv           erter.instantiateNewInstance(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:308)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConv           erter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:161)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshall           er.java:82)
        ... 19 more

I don't understand this-could anyone please help-I have been struggling with this for ages. evosuite documentation is available at www.evosuite.org/documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was an internal evosuite error, caused, for some reason, by running it in cygwin.

Comment: Are you answering your own question? Or trying to add further information to your question? If it is the second case, it is better to edit your original question or add comment to your original post.